# Prevent duplicate toast Chakra UI

Tags: chakra-ui

I am using `chakra` to prevent notifications from showing if they are already showing [this](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/feedback/toast#preventing-duplicate-toast).

But now I separated the notifications into another component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createStandaloneToast } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import theme from '../theme';
    
const Notification = (title, description, status) => {
    const toast = createStandaloneToast({ theme: theme });

    toast({
        title: title,
        description: description,
        status: status,
        duration: 3000,
        position: 'bottom-right',
        isClosable: true,
      });

    return <></>;
};

export default Notification;
```

And in my components I use it as follows:

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
...

const RemoveToDo = () => {
    const remove = () => {
        ...
        Notification('Tarea eliminada.', 'Has eliminado la tarea.', 'success');
    };
};
```

How could you prevent them from duplicating now?

When I was using `useToast` and I didn't have separate notifications in another component, I was able to prevent them from being duplicated with this:

```js
const id = 2;
if (!toast.isActive(id)) {
    toast({
        id: 2,
        title: 'Error al crear la tarea.',
        description: 'Ya tienes una tarea con esa descripción.',
        status: 'warning',
        duration: 3000,
        position: 'bottom-right',
        isClosable: true,
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, first of all you are creating a Notification Component, as you are returning jsx in there, but you are recieving multiple params, components does not support this. if you want to create a toast from inside of a function you can simply use this

```
const { toast } = createStandaloneToast()

const makeToast = ({message}) => {
  toast({
    id:"my-toast",
    title: 'A Toast!',
    description: message,
  })
}
```

You can prevent duplicate toasts by simply giving your toast an id

Also create your standalone toast outside your component as I have done it above. This should prevent duplication and is also an optimized solution.

You can simply trigger toast from any of your function by calling this makeToast function

```
function someFn(){
   makeToast()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thx for your question. I also use chakra UI and used toast . I think there are two options: first: make an object, and second: make a Higher Order Function.
I preferred the first one... because the second one will be more complex with typescript.
here my solution:

```
const defaultToastProps = {
 position: "top-right" as ToastPosition,
 duration: 2000,
 isClosable: true,
};

const submitHandler = () => {
 Axios.post("/user/register", formData)
   .then((res) => {
     console.log(res);
     toast({
       title: "Account created.",
       description: "We've created your account for you.",
       status: "success",
       ...defaultToastProps,
     });
     nav("/login");
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     if (err.response) {
       console.log(err.response.data.message);
       toast({
         title: "Something went wrong.",
         description: err.response.data.message,
         status: "error",
         ...defaultToastProps,
       });
     } else {
       console.log(err);
       toast({
         title: "Something went wrong.",
         description: "server-error",
         status: "error",
         ...defaultToastProps,
       });
     }
   });
};
```